# How to do strike through string for javascript

Tags: javascript, string, strikethrough

I want to strike through text in Javascript but I can't seem to get the code to work.

```
var message = document.getElementById('helloWorld');
setTextContent(message, 'hello world!'.strike());
```

Would appreciate any help.  Would also like to do it without using css.

Should Also mention that these lines of code are inside another function called totalPackage() which runs when the user clicks a button.  I want my message <strike>hello world!</strike> to be displayed when this other function is called.

Comment: can you show us `setTextContent`? You are most likely setting the `innerText` rather than `innerHTML`

Comment: See my answer. It gives you a working example... and doesn't use any CSS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this

```
var message = document.getElementById('helloWorld');
message.innerHTML='<del>helloworld</del>'
```

Answer (score 18):

Using **[Unicode Character 'COMBINING LONG STROKE OVERLAY' (U+0336)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0336/index.htm)**

> E̶x̶a̶m̶p̶l̶e̶

```js
function strikeThrough(text) {
  return text
    .split('')
    .map(char => char + '\u0336')
    .join('')
}
```

```html
<input oninput="document.querySelector('#output').innerText = strikeThrough(this.value)" placeholder="type here"><p id="output"></p>
```

To undo it, simply remove all the `\u0336` characters from the string.

```
string.replace(/[\u0336]/g, '')
```

Comment: simply easy yet mesmerizing

Comment: I wish you would mention how to undo it as well ? :)

Comment: @KickButtowski Replace the `.map(...)` line with `.filter(char => char !== '\u0336')`. Basically find and remove all the `\u0336` characters from the string.

Comment: you should add this to ur post imho . 

Comment: I did this instead of your way string.replace(/[\u0335]/g, ""). it is more concise ?

Comment: @KickButtowski Hmm, I didn't know escaped Unicode chars could work in regex like that. TIL. Yeah, I guess it is more concise if it works! Updated the answer with your method.

Comment: `string.replace(/[\u0336]/g, '')` not `s̶t̶r̶i̶n̶g̶.̶r̶e̶p̶l̶a̶c̶e̶(̶/̶[̶\̶u̶0̶3̶3̶5̶]̶/̶g̶,̶ ̶'̶'̶)`

Answer (score 0):

If `#helloWorld` is a DIV, then you can set its innerHTML property.

```
<div id="helloWorld"></div>

function setTextContent(msg, str) {
    msg.innerHTML = str;
}

var message = document.getElementById('helloWorld');
setTextContent(message, 'hello world!'.strike());
```

Here's a fiddle to demonstrate: **http://jsfiddle.net/SXFLw/**

Comment: I should have mentioned above but I have this line of code inside another function called totalPackage() so when I call totalPackage(), I want it to write the string with the strikethrough without any css.  No DIV.

Comment: A DIV is not CSS... it's HTML. You need to learn some basic HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to do it respective to the format in you question, you can make a string prototype method to handle it. **[`String.strike()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/strike)** is non standard and you may run into browser compatibility issues.

```
String.prototype.strike = function() {
    return '<div class="strike">'+ this +'</div>';
};

// <div class="strike"> hello world! </div>
var test = 'hello world!'.strike();
```

Then in CSS you can make a class named `strike` like so.

```
.strike {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z7LjN/)**

Comment: No, no, no. There's already a JavaScript method str.strike(): http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_strike.asp.

Comment: Did you really just reference to *w3 schools?* [.strike()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/strike) is non standard.

Comment: Sorry, I assumed you thought the problem was with the `strike` method. That's a good point, in pointing out that MDN is a better reference. Though clearly, the OP's problem is conceptual.

Answer (score 0):

The right syntax of `strike()` is  `str.strike()`

so use like

```
 setTextContent(message, 'hello world!'.strike());
```

Comment: This is exactly what I have and this is what it shows: <strike>hello world!</strike>

Comment: what is `document.getElementById('helloWorld');` its div or textbox?

Comment: strike will not supported in html5

Answer (score 0):

There's already a [`strike`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/strike) method in JavaScript, however it seems to be non-standard.
The normal implementation simply wraps the string in a `strike` tag. However, please note that the result isin't simple text anymore, so setting the `textContent` propert of a text node to `'some string'.strike()` would not give the expected result. It would just display the markup as plain text in the document.

You could always implement a polyfill, like:

```
if (!(typeof String.prototype.strike === 'function')) {
    String.prototype.strike = function () {
        return '<strike>' + this + '</strike>';
    };
}
```

Comment: while `Strike.strike` is non standard, `<strike>` is also deprecated. [Source](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/graphics.html#edef-STRIKE)

Comment: @AustinBrunkhorst Well that's the default implementation in Chrome.

Comment: Yes in Chrome, but that's the problem. It's not available for all browsers.

Comment: @AustinBrunkhorst, That's why I suggested a polyfill. Even on MDN strike is implemented with the strike tag.