# bold and italic text for javascript, using unicode symbols

Tags: javascript, unicode

To make text strikethrough using unicode, I have been using this:

```
function strikeThrough(text) {
  return text
    .split('')
    .map(char => char + '\u0336')
    .join('')
}
```

Reference:

[How to do strike through string for javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18285291/how-to-do-strike-through-string-for-javascript)

My question is: is there a similar way to do this for Bold and Italic as well, by adding a unicode character in the same manner? I'm trying to avoid an html-based solution. For example:

```
function boldText(text) {
  return text
    .split('')
    .map(char => char + '????')
    .join('')
}

function italicText(text) {
  return text
    .split('')
    .map(char => char + '????')
    .join('')
}
```

Comment: Don't. What are you going to do with the string? Use a markup language, not Unicode.

Comment: In my application, I wish to be able to copy/paste the resulting text to a plain text editor. When I use <b> or <i> (or CSS), the style does not carry over (the same is true when using the strikethrough html <s>). However, when I use the strikethrough unicode method, copy/paste from website to plain text editor works perfectly. Thus, I'm hoping to follow the pattern that I currently use for strikethrough in the bold/italic situation.

Comment: If it's a *plain text* editor, it's not supposed to have styles? I would be worried about weird glyphs in there, and you cannot really *edit* that text then so no point in using an editor.

Comment: No.  The strikethrough example is using character combination - i.e. overlaying a dash on each original character.  There is no way to achieve bold and italic effects using that approach.

Comment: @MrIncredible thanks, I think that's the answer that I was looking for, actually. It's ok if it's truly not possible, I just needed to know for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this library can do what you are looking for:

https://github.com/davidkonrad/toUnicodeVariant

This is a Javascript function to convert a string into different kind of ⓤⓝⓘⓒⓞⓓⓔ variants :P