# Copy to clipboard with styles and show the text with styles when pasted

Tags: javascript, dom

i have a project that needs to copy strikethrough text here is the example site

https://convertcase.net/strikethrough-text-generator/

i want to strikethrough the text and copy it with the styles and when i paste it somewhere it should show the same strikethrough text with styles.

The website above applies styles even in google chrome search bar.

How can i do it with the javascript ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The site you referenced generates a **'modified'** version of the string, with a special Unicode character between every letter. I used [Babelstone](https://www.babelstone.co.uk/Unicode/whatisit.html) to check the contents of the modified string.

If you enter 'ABC', then convert, the website add a **"COMBINING LONG STROKE OVERLAY {strikethrough}"** after every character.

The problem here is not *'styles'* (I am assuming you are talking about CSS styles), but rather you would have to add the Unicode character above after every character.

**TLDR**:
After every character in 'ABC', add the U+0336 character, then copy it to the clipboard.

You can get the Unicode character [here](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+0336).

Comment: your comment saved me. Thank you so much also found this :) 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18285291/how-to-do-strike-through-string-for-javascript